# How to trim everything after certain character in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to format the email address in my table by removing everything starting the @.  Also I would like to replace the underscore with blank space.

For example:
`FirstName_LastName@gmail.com`

I would like the above email to be changed like this:
`FirstName LastName`

Here is my code but this trims everything after the @ and that is what i want. But how can i replace the underscore with blank.  I want all in one statement using the update function.  How can I do that?

```
SELECT 
     left (Email, CHARINDEX('@',Email)-1)
  FROM [Dashboard]
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(Email, CHARINDEX('@',Email)-1),'_',' ')
FROM [DSR].[dbo].[RCA_Dashboard]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful if you need to remove all after the last certain character:

```
Declare @String nvarchar(max) = 
  'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\log.ldf'


select reverse(substring(reverse (@String), CHARINDEX('\', reverse (@String))+1, len(reverse (@String))));
```