# trim the column value string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Query, I need the values as below using select query of my column.
Result has to be the text after the first space ' ' and before the first '('

## Source Column

```
create Table Test_Table (Column1 Varchar(50))
Insert into Test_Table Values
('0636 KAVITHI (LOC)'),
('0638 SRI KRISHNA (NAT)'),
('0639 SELVAM'),
('0643 GOOD SERVICE (LOC)'),
('0644 FINA CARE EVENT (LOC)')
```

I need get the string found between first ' ' and the '('

## Expected Result

```
KAVITHI
SRI KRISHNA
SELVAM
GOOD SERVICE
FINA CARE EVENT
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trim everything after certain character in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345880/how-to-trim-everything-after-certain-character-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach without using an OUTER APPLY.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Column1 LIKE '%(%' 
            THEN SUBSTRING(RIGHT(Column1,LEN(Column1)-CHARINDEX(' ',Column1)),0,
                 CHARINDEX('(',RIGHT(Column1,LEN(Column1)-CHARINDEX(' ',Column1)),0)) 
            ELSE RIGHT(Column1,LEN(Column1)-CHARINDEX(' ',Column1)) 
            END AS Trimmed
FROM Test_Table
```

OUTPUT

```
Trimmed
KAVITHI
SRI KRISHNA
SELVAM
GOOD SERVICE
FINA CARE EVENT
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69dd1/20/0

Comment: Why would it be preferred to have so much code repetition *(and extra overhead of `LEN()`, nesting `RIGHT()`s inside `SUBSTRING()`s, etc)* , rather than using `APPLY`?

Comment: I wasn't saying it was preferred, just another approach, possible faster execution. I tried to compare them but yours brings up an error `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Comment: Thanks for the note, I didn't see the OP included scenarios with no `(`.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

`CHARINDEX()` can be used to find the position of specific characters.

`OUTER APPLY` can be used to find the position of the space and brace characters, and store them in a place that you can re-use them.

`SUBSTRING()` can be used to find the text between the space and the brace.

**EDIT:** *Added `CASE` to cope with values that contain no `(`.*

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(
       test_table.column1,    -- the field we're searching
       stats.idx_space + 1,   -- starting from the character after the first space
       CASE
           WHEN stats.idx_brace > stats.idx_space
           THEN stats.idx_brace
           ELSE stats.idx_eos
       END
       -
       stats.idx_space        -- for as many characters as there are between the space and the brace
   )
FROM
   test_table
OUTER APPLY
(
   SELECT
       CHARINDEX(' ', test_table.column1)   AS idx_space,  -- position of the first space
       CHARINDEX('(', test_table.column1)   AS idx_brace,  -- position of the first brace
       LEN(test_table.column1)              AS idx_eos     -- position of the end-of-string
)
    AS stats
```

**EDIT:** *A single "line", as requested.*

Do note that forcing this as a single line does make this harder to read, maintain and adapt.  One of `APPLY`'s strongest use-cases is to maintain DRY *(Don't Repeat Yourself)* principles.

This query repeats several parts several times:
- `find the first space` repeated 2 times
- `find the first brace` repeated 3 times

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(
       test_table.column1,
       CHARINDEX(' ', test_table.column1) + 1,
       CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX('(', test_table.column1) > CHARINDEX(' ', test_table.column1)
           THEN CHARINDEX('(', test_table.column1)
           ELSE LEN(test_table.column1)
       END
       -
       CHARINDEX('(', test_table.column1)
   )
FROM
   test_table
```

Comment: how to get this in single linek